# Can a socket instance send and receive more than once?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

This question may be too vague and I might have it shut down...

I've been trying to figure out how to establish TCP/IP connections for over a week now and I'm still totally lost on how they exactly work.  All the examples I've seen consist of sending one message and, sometimes, relaying one message back and subsequently closing the socket.  This is very nice, but not very useful for a steady connection to another computer.

I'm trying to determine how, exactly, long term data exchange channels are established with TCP/IP in c# .NET framework.  Is the socket instance accepted and then there is an indefinite read and indefinite write buffer open for both the client and server?  Or is one packet received and one returned, the socket is closed, and another instance of a socket.Listen is invoked for the next packet exchange?

I even bought a book and all it contains is instances of single packet exchanges.  I'm too used to seeing the "user interface" concept of "server" and "client" where a connection is long term data exchange and am trying to figure out if that really means that a steady connection is just a bunch of quickly opening and closing of sockets for quick packet exchanges.

Maybe someone could direct me to a web source which has good information on establishing a long term stream connection to another computer which could allow multiple exchanges of packets?

I may have just had bad luck with examples - but I don't really want to sweat and fuss over trying to code something completely new to me without knowing exactly what direction I'm aiming for - I.E. - if I pass each new incoming connection to a separate thread - will that constitute an indefinitely open channel between the client and server for an indefinite number of packet exchange before one of them calls "close()?"

Comment: Please try asking a specific question.

Comment: Is a socket instance which is not closed a steady two-way connection in which both the server and client can write and read at will an indefinite number of times until "close()" is called or is it a one time stream instance that can be written to once by the client and written back to once by the server?

Comment: Yes, of _course_ it's a "steady two-way connection". You should post a specific question that led you to believe that it might _not_ be a steady, two-way connection.

Comment: I don't really have a specific question "which led me to believe that."  Unfortunately, because I'm still trying to figure out how exactly it works, I've not been able to experiment with implementing a steady two-way connection and hence haven't come across a specific programming problem.  I can't try to program it until I know what the algorithm is supposed to resemble.

I've just been unfortunate in examples then as they've not shown repeated send and receive on the same socket instance - just a one packet send and one one packet return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The examples to which you're referring are presumably limiting themselves to a single exchange for the sake of simplification.

The interface of a TCP Socket to the programmer is very similar to that of a file - you are reading to and writing from a stream of bytes.  In fact, TCP doesn't even expose the concept of "Packets" to the programmer, and the underlying IP layer is permitted to break apart and merge TCP packets as it sees fit.

For example in the following code, there's no guarantee that the two messages will arrive in the same packet, and in fact, there's no reliable way for the receiver to even know, since from his perspective, he's simply receiving a stream of bytes:

```
public void SocketExample(IPEndPoint endPoint) {
    Socket sender = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, 
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    Socket.Connect(endPoint);

    byte[] message1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("These might be arrive");
    byte[] message2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(" in the same packet!");

    sender.Send(message1);
    sender.Send(message2);
}
```

So in short, yes, send as many messages as you want through the same TCP connection, and think more in terms of reading and writing from a byte stream, rather than sending and receiving individual packets.

[edit]
It should be noted that TCP is a [full-duplex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplex_%28telecommunications%29#Full-duplex) protocol, so it's more like writing to one stream, and reading from another, entirely separate stream, while the other end is reading from/writing to opposite streams.
[/edit]

In the case where you really do need to fire discrete packets back and forth, consider [UDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol).

Comment: One other suggestion for sending packets back and forth - consider `WebSocket`s - these are built on top of TCP (and HTTP), are very easy to use (via OWIN) and provide a `endOfMessage` flag.

Comment: When does the stream get overwritten or does it?  When I think about writing to a file stream, if I indefinitely add information to it, it's going to get very long.  When it is "read" by the recipient does the data in the stream pass out of scope?  And, do the "read" and "write" streams from the server's point of view constitute separate streams or is it possible to overwrite incoming data if, for example, I placed some sort of delay between a read and a write operation on the server's side...

Comment: @ThisHandleNotInUse There are always going to be limitations on how much data the reader can buffer, and if you continue to send ridiculous amounts of data without reading it on the receiving end, of course some of it will be lost.  When that data is "read" by the recipient, then yes, the underlying socket implementation will discard it to free up that space in its internal buffers.  Regarding separate read/write streams, TCP is a [full-duplex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplex_(telecommunications)#Full-duplex) protocol, meaning that the read/write streams are separate.

Comment: Anyway, thanks...  This is just one of those humps in programming for me that is pretty confusing at the moment but in a month or so should feel like "old tricks."

Isaac Supeene - thank you as well.  That's very helpful.  As I'm sure you're aware, being confused about how an implementation works causes it to be somewhat difficult to try to implement to present more specific problems.

Comment: No problem.  Glad you found it helpful.